# Ruby email check (RFC 2822)

Tags: ruby, regex, email

Does anyone know what the regular expression in Ruby is to verify an email address is in proper RFC 2822 email format?

What I want to do is:

```
string.match(RFC_2822_REGEX)
```

where "RFC_2822_REGEX" is the regular expression to verify if my string is in valid RFC 2882 form.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use a regular expression to validate an email addresses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-use-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-addresses)

Answer (score 12):

You can use the [mail](http://rubygems.org/gems/mail) gem to parse any string according to RFC2822 like so:

```
def valid_email( value )
  begin
   return false if value == ''
   parsed = Mail::Address.new( value )
   return parsed.address == value && parsed.local != parsed.address
  rescue Mail::Field::ParseError
    return false
  end
end
```

This checks if the email is provided, i.e. returns `false` for an empty address and also checks that the address contains a domain.

Comment: This doesn't parse valid emails listed in RFC3696, including "Abc\@def@example.com". :(

Answer (score 2):

http://theshed.hezmatt.org/email-address-validator

Does regex validation based on RFC2822 rules (it's a monster of a regex, too), it can also check that the domain is valid in DNS (has MX or A records), and do a test delivery to validate that the MX for the domain will accept a message for the address given. These last two checks are optional.

Answer (score 1):

Try  [this:](http://tfletcher.com/lib/)

Comment: this REGEX allows for emails like "test@example/x.com" and therefor "test@example/////////////////////////////////x.com"