# rails - REGEX for email validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looking for a regex to validate an email to learn if it's valid or not.. I have the following:

```
def is_a_valid_email?(email)
    email_regex = %r{
      ^ # Start of string
      [0-9a-z] # First character
      [0-9a-z.+]+ # Middle characters
      [0-9a-z] # Last character
      @ # Separating @ character
      [0-9a-z] # Domain name begin
      [0-9a-z.-]+ # Domain name middle
      [0-9a-z] # Domain name end
      $ # End of string
    }xi # Case insensitive

    (email =~ email_regex)
end
```

Problem with the above is `XXX_XXX@Xxx.com` does not return as valid when it should be. Any thoughts or suggestions for a better regex?

Thanks

Comment: I think the underscore issues is just one of many where the above would fail (yield false positives or negatives). Do you really *need* to validate beyond "contains a `@` character"? The thread ["What is the best regular expression for validating email addresses?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses) contains more details.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby email check (RFC 2822)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/535600/ruby-email-check-rfc-2822)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My shot at this (see comment and link above):

```
^.+@.+$
```

Comment: @noodl Is that Ruby specific? I've never seen the `/` characters carry any signaficance in regex.

Comment: Yes, in Ruby and Perl regex literals use `/` by default. The equivalent "bare" regex would be just `@`

Comment: Thansk jens, so simple. How do I assign that? email_regex = ^.+@.+$ errors

Comment: Is this fine? email_regex = /^.+@.+$/

Comment: @AnApprentice I don't know much about Ruby, but I'd do `email_regex = %r{^.+@.+$}` if I were to hack something together :)

Comment: but with that RE this strings are valid, too: @a@a.com a@a

Comment: @MegaTux Strictly speaking, `a@a` is valid with `a` serving as a TLD. You may be right, however, that using `@a` as the [`local-part`](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322#section-3.4.1) (in `@a@a`) is not invalid.

Comment: `@@üüü@` will be validated correctly. I don't know, why this got upvoted at all. It's just wrong.

Comment: /^[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+$/i.   @noodl, /^.+@.+$/ is not at all equivalent to /@/ btw.

Comment: +1 @eagspoo is right that /^.+@.+$/ is not at all equivalent to /@/  I'm surprised that that completely wrong statement collected 5 (by the moment) upvotes. Guys go read books!
p.s. sure that regex is very bad for validation.

Comment: Make sure you use \A and \z for checking beginning and end of the whole string not ^ and $ which check just the _line_.

Comment: But this gonna be start with any word like numerical,wild characters etc,try this \A[\w+.-]+\@[a-z]+.[a-z]{3}\z

Comment: the above regex would also let through t@t. But that is not a correct email address!

Comment: @RobertReiz `t@t` is a valid email address, sent to the dns host `t.`, just as `t@localhost` is perfectly fine.  Practical is another matter.

Comment: Do not use regex to validate email addresses!  (unless you're happy with false positives/negatives, I suppose).  There are far too many cases to cover, and some -- such as nested comments -- cannot be properly covered via regex.  tl;dr: regexes cannot properly validate email addresses.  If you try, you will most assuredly fail.

Comment: @TerraAshley There is nothing wrong with using an extremely permissive regex to  catch silly mistakes like entering a physical street address into an email address field

Comment: @ilovebigmacs That's fine. Being overly permissive is preferable to rejecting valid emails because your regex is too specific.

Comment: Hi this one allows space

Answer (score 25):

```
validates_format_of :email, 
  :with => /^(|(([A-Za-z0-9]+_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\.+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9]+@((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})$/i
```

Don't ask me to explain it! That was from a validation plugin that I've since lost track of as all I needed was the email regex.

Comment: This regex identifies empty strings as valid emails. You should omit the outer parentheses and the pipe in the second character, which is the one accepting empty strings `/^(([A-Za-z0-9]+_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\.+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9]+@((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/i`

Comment: This should be used with `validates_presence_of :email`, that way they get the proper error message when it is empty.

Comment: This will fail against new TLDs like `.international`.

Comment: or the crazier, but valid .XN--CLCHC0EA0B2G2A9GCD

Comment: If you want to allow Gmail aliases using `+`, add `(\+)` in the valid values. The regex becomes: `^(|(([A-Za-z0-9]+_+)|(\+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\.+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9]+@((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})$`

Answer (score 19):

Not enough reputation to add a comment but if you are going to use the Devise regexp, and you are already using Devise itself, then you can simply use:

`validates :email, presence: true, format: Devise.email_regexp`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow

Comment: Warning: `Devise#email_regexp` accepts `test@providercom` as a valid email.

Comment: oooh you should make a PR!

Comment: Warning: Devise#email_regexp will also reject valid emails like bob@xyx-pd.com

Comment: oooh you should make a PR!

Answer (score 14):

@jensgram's answer is really good, but it actually still allows for an email without a domain, e.g. foo@bar is as valid as foo@bar.com.

Here's a slight variation on it that requires string@string.string:

`/\A\S+@.+\.\S+\z/`

or, more readable (though the parentheses aren't needed):

`/\A(\S+)@(.+)\.(\S+)\z/`

*[Play around with this](http://rubular.com/?regex=%5CA%5CS%2B%40.%2B%5C.%5CS%2B%5Cz&test=foo@bar.com)*

*Note: this regex is better than many, more complex ones, because of how incredibly diverse an email is allowed to be. Technically, an email can even use spaces if wrapped in quotes, e.g. "This is a valid email"@email.com

*Edit: I've replaced the `^` and `$` with `\A` and `\z` to prevent a multiline anchor error in rails testing.

*Edit: Thanks to @Barry for noticing that the regex allowed white spaces. Updated the regex with \S to prevent emails with improper whitespaces. Multiple dots are still allowed as email@foo.bar.com is an acceptable address.

Comment: @Barry, emails actually can be email@foo.bar.com (having two dots)--Chrome takes that as an acceptable email. Good catch though on the whitespace. I've updated the regex appropriately.

Comment: Pretty good this one! Except as noted in previous, the TLD changes now make: {code}.XN--CLCHC0EA0B2G2A9GCD{code} valid

Answer (score 12):

URI module has a build-in regexp

```rb
URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP
```

Comment: Warning: URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP
 accepts test@gmail as a valid email.

Answer (score 9):

```
/\b[A-Z0-9._%a-z\-]+@(?:[A-Z0-9a-z\-]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}\z/
```

This is what I use to validate email.

Source: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: Don't do this.  This regex will fail for email of the format, foo+bar@dingleberry.com.   +stuff is valid for emails and is an important part of emails for many people and many apps.   Also instead of repeating all the upper and lowercase matchers, just make the entire thing case insensitive.

Comment: chris+amazon@idontknow.com is a valid email. The +amazon is a tag for the address chris@idontknow.com. [More infos for emailaddress tagging](http://www.stevejenkins.com/blog/2011/03/how-to-use-address-tagging-usertagexample-com-with-postfix)

Answer (score 5):

Most of these other answers are too restrictive or allow addresses that are clearly wrong.  So it's better to give up on being too strict, which will frustrate users and just get the main things right.

**1. The most common use-case:**

```rb
    validates :email, ..., format: { with: /\A[^@\s]+@([^@.\s]+\.)+[^@.\s]+\z/ }
```

**2. To also allow `root@localhost` or `homer@blinky`, use this:**

```rb
    validates :email, ..., format: { with: /\A[^@\s]+@([^@.\s]+\.)*[^@.\s]+\z/ }
```

None of the above replaces looking for CAPTCHAs, dns records, dns domain blacklists, IP blacklists and confirmation emails.

For real email domain validation, this can be used instead: https://gist.github.com/9200104

This horse is thoroughly beaten now, and being made into kibble.

Answer (score 4):

correct format: email@domain.com

rules:

- no whitespace
- character prefix + @ + domain + . + character suffix

simple answer:

```
def validate_email(email)
  (email =~ %r{^\S+@\S+\.\S+$}xi).present?
end
```

examples:

```
'email' # false (no '@' and no domain)
'email@' # false (no domain)
'email@domain' # false (domain format without '.')
'em ail@d omain.com' # false (whitespace included)
'@domain.com' # false (no character prefix)
'email@domain.' # false (no character suffix)
'email@domain.com' # true
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an email regex that I've been using for a while:

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b
```

It's from [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)

Comment: I just put an edit in queue for Mblake's response showing the same source. For Ruby, to validate, though, you'll want:
/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i

Answer (score 1):

use: `/\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/`

> It asserts that there are no @ symbols or whitespaces in either the localpart or the domain, and that there is a single @ symbol separating the localpart and the domain.

More importantly: **require email verification**

As more tlds are being created, this is forward thinking.

This is from [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise.rb#L113)
, an industry standard for authentication.

Comment: It allows `a@b.com...`

Comment: @Barry why is that a bad thing?

Answer (score 1):

`^.+@[\w]+\S[^\s]+$`

A short improvement to first answer

Answer (score 0):

For email validation, I come up with this regular expression,

```
/^[\w\d]+@[\w\d]+(\.[\w\d]+)+$/
```

Don't know how much it will help you but working fine for me.

If anyone find it failing for any email address please reply me so I will be able to work more on this.

Comment: Emails and domains can both have non-alphanumeric characters. For example foo.bar@great-example.com.

Answer (score -1):

In non-English locales you may need to verify emails with accented (unicode) characters such as čšēīū etc.

This method checks for a returned `nil` as a sign for a failed email validation in such locales:

```
def validate_unicode_email email
  /\A[\w\u00C0-\u017F\-]+(\.[\w\u00C0-\u017F\-]+)?@[\w\u00C0-\u017F\-]+\.[\w]{2,6}$/.match email
end
```

This will pass emails like `name.surname@gmail.com`, `āpsis@mājās.lv`, `test_email@test_domain.org`

Answer (score -2):

Here's what we use.

We assume it's "something" @ "something" . "something" (2-4 characters). It should cover any "regular" email.

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/
```

Comment: do not use this. chris+amazon@idontknow.com is a valid emailaddress that won't match with this regex!

Answer (score -3):

```
validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]+\z/i
```