# Is there a better way to conditionally allow a user to sign in with a 'username' or an 'email' with ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was able to allow users to sign-in with either their username or email by implementing this bit of code in my model concerns.

```
module ClassMethods
    def authenticate(username, email, password)
      user = User.find_by(username: username)
      user_email = User.find_by(email: email)
      return unless user || user_email

      if user
        user.send :new_token
        user.authenticate password
      elsif user_email
        user_email.send :new_token
        user_email.authenticate password
      end
    end
  end

  included do
    has_secure_password
    before_create :set_token
    after_find :fix_up_token
    validates :email, uniqueness: true
    validates :email, presence: true
    validates :username, uniqueness: true
    validates :username, presence: true
    validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, on: :create
  end
```

I originally was trying to create a conditional for 'user' with the find_by method but I didn't have any luck. I ended up with the idea of creating 'user_email' as a work around and it works, but I feel like there has to be a way to do this with one variable.

**Update**

I was able to get it working with two of the answers below.

This one here from [max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/544825/max):

```
def authenticate(username, email, password)
      user = User.where(email: email)
                 .or(User.where(username: username)).take
      return unless user

      user.send :new_token
      user.authenticate password
    end
```

And this one here from [Sajjad Umar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7009747/sajjad-umar):

```
def authenticate(username, email, password)
      user = User.find_by(username: username) || User.find_by(email: email)
      return if user.blank?

      user.send :new_token
      user.authenticate password
    end
```

**Update 2**

[Sean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4187231/sean) recommended using a regex to scan the input for email format. I have the requirement for email format covered already, but I did want to make sure that a user can not create a username that matches an email of a different user. So, I placed format validations on the username using regex.

```
included do
    has_secure_password
    before_create :set_token
    after_find :fix_up_token
    validates :email, uniqueness: true
    validates :email, presence: true
    validates :username, uniqueness: true
    validates :username, presence: true
    validates :username, format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9]+\z/,
                                   message: 'only allows letters and numbers' }
    validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, on: :create
  end
```

Thanks to everyone for helping me out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify the `authenticate` method as follows

```
def authenticate(username, email, password)
   user = User.find_by(username: username) || User.find_by(email: email)
   return if user.blank?

   user.send :new_token
   user.authenticate password
end
```

This has two benefits over your code

1. If User is found with username, no query will be made to find a user based on the email address
2. No code repetition

And I don't recommend using the `where` clause because it will search the whole table and return a collection. Whereas the `find_by` method will return the first matching object.

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. I originally tried something similar, but I was missing the `.blank?` part.

Comment: "And I don't recommend using the where clause because it will search the whole table and return a collection. Whereas the find_by method will return the first matching object." This is nonsense. When you use where with `take` or `first` it adds a LIMIT clause to the query which is exactly how `.find_by` limits the fetched records.

Comment: Thanks, @max that adds to my knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `where` to create a query with a or clause:

```
def authenticate(identifier, password)
  user = User.where(email: identifier)
             .or(User.where(username: identifier)).take
  return unless user
  user.new_token 
  user.authenticate password
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I tried this solution out, but ran into trouble with the arguments. It definitely looks like it should work, I just need to dig in a little deeper and figure out how to replace 'email' and 'username' with 'identifier' in the controller... I think.

Comment: Well you could change the signature back and add`identifier = username || email` to the top of the method. I just thought the signature was kind of silly since you only need one parameter.

Comment: Thanks again. This is definitely a failure on my part, not on your answer. I fully expect this will work and I plan to try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your usernames cannot be formatted like emails, I would recommend using a regex to scan the input for email format, and following the "input is email" logic if so, otherwise follow the "input is username".

Example taken from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17396426/4187231):

```rb
def authenticate(username_or_email, password)
  user = get_user(username_or_email)

  return if user.nil?

  user.send :new_token
  user.authenticate password
end

def get_user(username_or_email)
  if is_email?(username_or_email)
    User.find_by(email: username_or_email)
  else
    User.find_by(username: username_or_email)
  end
end

def is_email?(string)
  email_regex = /\A(\S+)@(.+)\.(\S+)\z/

  return true if string ~= email_regex

  false
end
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. I was planning on figuring this out next. I have some restrictions on the client, but I assume it's better practice to have the restrictions and requirements on the back end.

Comment: Edited to place in context of the authenticate method you had in your question.
Also @max not sure what you mean there.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems.