# Parse text email addresses using XPath, NOT //A[startswith(@href, 'mailto:')]

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I want to extract email addresses from few different websites. If they are in active link format, I can do this using

```
//A[starts-with(@href, 'mailto:')]
```

But some of them are in just text format `example@domain.com`, not a link, so I would like to select a path to element that contains `@` inside

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/535600/ruby-email-check-rfc-2822

Comment: I have no idea what to use, I've tried tried everything that came to my mind but nothing worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I would like to select a path to element that contains @ inside

**Use**:

```
//*[contains(., '@')]
```

**It seems to me that what you actually wanted is to select elements that have a text-node child that contains "@". If this is so, use:**

```
//*[contains(text(), '@')]
```

**XSLT - based verification:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
        "//*[contains(text(), '@')] "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<html>
 <body>
  <a href="xxx.com">xxx.com</a>
  <span>someone@xxx.com</span>
 </body>
</html>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the selected nodes are copied to the output**:

```
<span>someone@xxx.com</span>
```

Comment: //*[contains(., '@')] selects everything on a website

Comment: @Gargamel: No, it only selects element nodes, whose string value contains the "@" character -- this is what you said you wanted...

Comment: When I use for example "//p[contains(., '@')]" then the selection contain everything from <p> tag 
"<P><STRONG>Mail:</STRONG> example@gmail.com<BR><STRONG>Skype:</STRONG> loginskype</P>, 
when I use //*[contains(., '@')] then the selection contains 
everything from the website.

Comment: @Gargamel: Yes, but this is what you wanted. Try: `//*[contains(text(), '@')]`  -- I edited the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately no difference, still selecting everything on a website.

Comment: @Gargamel: That means that *every* element has a text-node child that contains "@". If you edit the question and provide a small XML document on which the XPath expression selects every element, we will clearly see that, if really this is the case, then every element in this document has a text-node-child containing "@".

Comment: @Gargamel: See the update to the answer -- only a single element is selected.

Answer (score 4):

You'll probably want to use a [regular expression](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html). They'll allow you to extract the email addresses, regardless of their context within a document. Here is a little test-driven example to get you started:

```
require "minitest/spec"
require "minitest/autorun"

module Extractor
  EMAIL_REGEX = /[\w]+@[\w]+\.[\w]+/

  def self.emails(document)
    (matches = document.scan(EMAIL_REGEX)).any? ? matches : false
  end
end

describe "Extractor" do
  it 'should extract an email address from plaintext' do
    emails = Extractor.emails("email@example.com")
    emails.must_include "email@example.com"
  end

  it 'should extract multiple email addresses from plaintext' do
    emails = Extractor.emails("email@example.com and email2@example2.com")
    emails.must_include "email@example.com", "email2@example2.com"
  end

  it 'should extract an email address from the href attribute of an anchor' do
    emails = Extractor.emails("<a href='mailto:email3@example3.com'>Email!</a>")
    emails.must_include "email3@example3.com"
  end

  it 'should extract multiple email addresses from both plaintext and within HTML' do
    emails = Extractor.emails("my@email.com OR <a href='mailto:email4@example4.com'>Email!</a>")
    emails.must_include "email4@example4.com", "my@email.com"
  end

  it 'should not extract an email address if there isn\'t one' do
    emails = Extractor.emails("email(at)address(dot)com")
    emails.must_equal false
  end

  it "should extract email addresses" do
    emails = Extractor.emails("email.address@domain.co.uk")
    emails.must_include "email.address@domain.co.uk"
  end
end
```

The last test fails because the regular expression doesn't anticipate the majority of valid email addresses. See if you use this as a starting point to come up with or find a better regular expression. To help build your regular expressions, check out [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/eHZpt5CXlX).

Comment: This is a really good answer. Here's a short one that passes your tests: /[\w._%+-]+@[\w._%+-]+\.[\w._%+-]+/